# Project Clearwater Sprout not working after update

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I had a working Clearwater installation on 6 virtual Machine.
After that I've updated the virtual machine the Sprout node is not starting anymore.
This are what I did:

First I've updated ubuntu server from 12 to 14.04.5

> sudo do-release-upgrade

After I've updated the clearwater installation:

> sudo apt-get update -o Dir::Etc::sourcelist="sources.list.d/clearwater.list" -o Dir::Etc::sourceparts="-" -o APT::Get::List-Cleanup="0" && sudo apt-get install clearwater-infrastructure && sudo clearwater-upgrade

Now If I try to start Sprout:

> sudo service sprout start

I've this error in /var/sprout/sprout_current

```
    07-12-2016 07:57:44.559 UTC Debug alarm.cpp:253: Reraising all alarms with a known state
    07-12-2016 07:57:44.586 UTC Verbose pjsip:          pjlib epoll I/O Queue created (0x7f520ecf64a8)
    07-12-2016 07:57:44.587 UTC Verbose pjsip: sip_endpoint.c Module "mod-msg-print" registered
    07-12-2016 07:57:44.587 UTC Debug pjsip: sip_transport. Transport manager created.
    07-12-2016 07:57:44.587 UTC Verbose pjsip: sip_endpoint.c Module "mod-tsx-layer" registered
    07-12-2016 07:57:44.587 UTC Verbose pjsip: sip_endpoint.c Module "mod-stateful-util" registered
    07-12-2016 07:57:44.587 UTC Verbose pjsip: sip_endpoint.c Module "mod-sprout-util" registered
    07-12-2016 07:57:44.587 UTC Error stack.cpp:325: Failed to start UDP transport for port 192 (Permission denied)
    07-12-2016 07:57:44.587 UTC Error pjsip: Assert failed: stack.cpp:767 status == 0
    07-12-2016 07:57:44.588 UTC Error main.cpp:1771: Error initializing stack Permission denied
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT (21/12/2016) - There is a bug in Sprout which can cause it to incorrectly attempt to start the services on an incorrect port. This is tracked in https://github.com/Metaswitch/sprout/issues/1656**

You are trying to start one of the Sproutlets on a privileged port (<1024), but Sprout doesn't run as root for security reasons, so it fails to bind to the port during startup.

You should check the configuration files in /etc/clearwater/ to see which service is configured on a low numbered port, and change it to a higher number.

Which release were you upgrading from?

By the way, you might be better asking for support on the Project Clearwater mailing list - http://lists.projectclearwater.org/mailman/listinfo/clearwater_lists.projectclearwater.org

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where can I chek the clearwater version?

Comment: You can use the package manager tools to look at what version the different packages - e.g. Sprout are.

Comment: Also, we've recently noticed that this is a bug in the latest version - see https://github.com/Metaswitch/sprout/issues/1656 

You can probably avoid this by not setting chronos_hostname in shared config, which you probably don't need anyway.